# InvalidOperationException al publicar el Web Service hecho en WCF,

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, iis, wcf

**Me muestra este error**

[InvalidOperationException: Ya se asoció otra versión al URI de escucha 'http://xxx/SERVICES/WS_SOE.svc'. Si dos extremos desean compartir el mismo ListenUri, deben compartir también la misma instancia del objeto de enlace. Los dos extremos conflictivos se especificaron en llamadas AddServiceEndpoint(), en un archivo de configuración o en una combinación de ambos. ]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo de tu servicio y como lo estas insertando para ayudarte.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el servicio lo tenia en ambiente test y funcionaba bien, pero cuando lo subi al servidor de produccion fallaba con ese error que les muestro

Gracias por los que quisieron ayudarme

Al final lo resolvi agregandole estas etiquestas en el Web.Config

```
<services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="SOEBehavior" name="WS_SOE.WS_SOE">
         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="SOEBasicHttpEndPoint" contract="WS_SOE.IWS_SOE" />            

     </service>
</services>

<behavior name="SOEBehavior">
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
</behavior>
```

Espero y les sirva a otros.